# What time is the daily train from Balykchy on Lake Issyk-Kul to Bishkek?

Tags: trains, kyrgyzstan, bishkek

There is a train line from Bishkek to Balykchy, on Lake Issyk-Kul, in Kyrgyzstan.

The train leaves Bishkek at 6.40am, and takes around 4 hours.  This is slower than minibuses or shared taxis, which I took from Bishkek TO the lake, but it's meant to be a really nice train trip, and I'd like to take it back on Sunday.

However, not being in Balykchy myself, I can't find the timetable for the return train - aside from 'in the afternoon' (which I'm assuming because we passed a train going in the other direction while in the minibus today).

If someone can find the timetable, I'd be highly appreciative!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to this blog](http://www.neweurasia.net/ru/kyrgyzstan/poezd-bishkek-balyikchi/)
(Saturday, 16 July 2011)

- From June, 17 to July 17: On Friday, Saturday and Sunday
- From July, 18 to August, 31: everyday

From Bishkek:  06.25,
From Balykchy: 16.47.
Tickets are: adults - 69 soms, children - 35 soms.

Support phones:  0312 418 107, 0312 664 808.

See also: [Official approval](http://www.ktj.kg/press/14-press-reliz-52-ot-11-iyulya-2011-goda.html) (Whole site in Russian)

Comment: Will be trying this tomorrow (Sunday), here's hoping! :) Thanks for the research!

Comment: and can confirm it left exactly at 16.47 :)